# CORS client and server side

Tags: javascript, cors

OK. So after reading about CORS I believe I understand it fairly well. However, I also read on the internet some articles and blogs. Then I was trying to practice and I noticed certain situations.

1) Some codes show the following

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS'){
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
}
```

Why do I need this? More over how are the subsequent request handled. From what I read it does the following: it send request (preflight) to check if the actual request can be made (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc. I also know there exceptions, like that trigger the preflight). 
So does it mean that when the request does a preflight, actually 2 requests are made? If so how does the flow go? 1st request check if the request can be made. 2nd request is sent if it is allowed.

2) I have also noticed that when I there is a preflight my session is empty.
3) If I make a request like this http://example.com it does not preflight. But this preflights http://www.example.com.

Can somebody show me how is the server side and the client side actually done.
I am using ajax to make my requests!

Comment: `Why do I need this?` read some [CORS information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: I have read the entire thing. I meant why do I need that piece of code. More specifically  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS'){
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
}